# Can't make google maps marker invisible on Ionic for IOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, ionic-framework, marker

I am working on a Ionic project that uses the Ionic Native google maps and I want to add to the map some markers and make them invisible.

The marker declaration looks something like this:

```
 this.map.addMarker({
        position: {lat: svLat + Math.abs(neLat - svLat) / 2, lng: svLong + Math.abs(neLong - svLong) / 2},
        visible: false,
        infoWindowAnchor: [-150, 50]
      });
```

My problem is that when I build the project for ios, the markers remain visible. The android build is working as expected. Any clues on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You, need to add Boolean type variable and import ionic platform like,

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

isVisible:boolean;

constructor(public platform:Platform) {
  if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    this.isVisible = true;
  }else{
    this.isVisible = false;
  }
}

this.map.addMarker({
    position: {lat: svLat + Math.abs(neLat - svLat) / 2, lng: svLong + Math.abs(neLong - svLong) / 2},
    visible: this.isVisible,
    infoWindowAnchor: [-150, 50]
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: My issue is not that I want to behave differently on ios than on other platforms. I want the same behaviour on all of them, and that is to make the markers invisible. The code works on android, but has no effect on ios from what i've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved after updating to newer version of google-maps plugin (2.2.8)